# is there a way to get all flags from Unleash in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unleash

I'm using @unleash/proxy-client-react package
I know that we can get specific flag from unleash by "useVariant" or "useFlag".
is there a way that we can get all flags at the same time from unleash or have access to unleash api response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `useFlags` hook. This will return an array with all flags:

```
import { useFlags } from '@unleash/proxy-client-react';

const Component = () => {
  const flags = useFlags();
  console.log(flags) // Returns all flags
  ...
}
```

It doesn't seem to be in the docs, but you can find the hook [in the source code.](https://github.com/Unleash/proxy-client-react/blob/main/src/useFlags.ts)

Comment: thanksssssssssssssssssss :))))))))))))